# on form validation if there's no words in the fields it returns the error but still submits the cgi file?

Tags: javascript, html, css, perl

to be more specific, when we submit our empty form which should have information in it should submit an alert saying "please enter a value" it does this but then after selecting okay on the alert it still sends the email on submit. I want it that if there's an error they must fulfill the requirements of the form before the email on submit can be sent. the code is:

this checks to see if there's any values in the fields

```
function notEmpty(elem, helperMsg) {
    if (elem.value.length >= 2) {
        return true;
        alert(helperMsg);
        elem.focus();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

the start of the form:

`<form method="get" onsubmit="notEmpty();" action="http://www.censoredgaming.co.uk/cgi-bin/mailer.pl">`

the submit button:

`<input type="submit" name='Submit' value="Send" onClick='notEmpty();'>`

any insight to our problem is most welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several reasons this will fail.

The first one you will encounter is, because you don't pass any arguments when you call `notEmpty`, the variable `elem` will be `undefined`. When you try to access a property (`value`) on it, an exception will be thrown and the function will stop.

Let's take this from the top.

First, we'll use a more modern method to apply the event handlers.

Provide a means to identify the form you want to deal with. An id attribute is a good general choice (but use a more meaningful name then I am):

```
<form id="myForm"
      method="get"
      action="http://www.censoredgaming.co.uk/cgi-bin/mailer.pl">
```

Next, get a reference to the form in the DOM and add an event listener to it:

```
document.getElementById('myForm').addEventListener('submit', notEmpty);
```

Note that you have to do this *after* the form has been added to the DOM. The easiest way to achieve this is to place your `<script>` after the `</form>` (just before `</body>` is a popular place). You can also use an event handler that fires when the DOM is ready or the document has loaded.

Old versions of Internet Explorer don't support `addEventListerner`, if you want to support them see [the MDN documentation which has a compatibility routine](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener).

Next, update the `notEmpty` function. Since it is an event handler, it will get one argument - an event object. It will also be called in the context of the element to which is is bound (the form).

```
function notEmpty(event) {
    var aForm = this;
}
```

You want to check that some element has a value of a certain length, but there is no sign of such an element in your question. Let's work with this example:

```
<label> Some data <input name="example"></label>
```

You can reference the element through the form's elements collection:

```
function notEmpty(event) {
    var aForm = this;
    var input = aForm.elements.example;
}
```

Now you can add your test:

```
function notEmpty(event) {
    var aForm = this;
    var input = aForm.elements.example;
    if (input.length >= 2) {

    } else {

    }
}
```

If you don't want the form to submit, then prevent the default action on the event:

```
function notEmpty(event) {
    var aForm = this;
    var input = aForm.elements.example;
    if (input.length >= 2) {
        // At least two characters, all is well
    } else {
       alert("An error");
       input.focus();
       event.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, although your code is much more tidier and readable than mine, the problem is still not resolved, i haven't actually hard-coded the website myself i am just filling in to assist so i am thinking the html could be the problem.

Comment: nevertheless we managed to get it fixed now, thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

Your first `return true` should be removed :P